# Creating a resizable div container with beveled corners

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a container with beveled/diagonal corners with the following properties:

- If there is an overflowing image content (`<img>` or `background-image`) it should clip to the beveled corners.
- If there is no image content, only the border should remain visible and the inside of the container should be rendered as either a solid background with alpha or transparent.
- The bevels of the corners should remain at the same angle (45 degrees), regardless of the size of the container.
- There must be an uniform border thickness: That means, same border thickness around the entire container, and its thickness mustn't scale along with the container.

I could do this in SVG, but I'd like to use CSS Grids to easily layout multiple of these containers.

Here is a visualization of these properties:

[image: Visualization of the properties I'd like.]

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62950455/8620333 .. I know better ones, will find them

Comment: another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62485073/8620333